# How to get Marker 's longitude and latitude Swift

Tags: swift, google-maps, swift3, google-maps-markers

I have map view and user can drag marker. When marker tapped, it display snippet that contain location of the marker.

How to get marker's longitude and latitude? if marker is dragged to another position.

Here's what I've done:

```
var latitude = -7.034323799999999
var longitude = 110.42400399999997
var displayAddress = [String]()

func customizeMap() {
    mapView.delegate = self
    let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: Double(latitude), longitude: Double(longitude), zoom: 17)
    mapView.animate(to: camera)

    let markerImage = UIImage(named: "ic_home_detail_marker_location")

    let markerView = UIImageView(image: markerImage)

    let marker = GMSMarker()
    marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(Double(latitude), Double(longitude))
    marker.isDraggable = true
    marker.iconView = markerView
    marker.snippet = displayAddress[0]
    mapView.selectedMarker = marker
    marker.map = mapView
}
```

right now i'm using static longitude and latitude

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For that you can use `didBeginDragging marker` and `didEndDragging marker` delegates method of `GMSMapViewDelegate`.

```
func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didDrag marker: GMSMarker) {
    print("Drag")
}

func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didBeginDragging marker: GMSMarker) {
    print("Old Coordinate - \(marker.position)")
}

func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didEndDragging marker: GMSMarker) {
    print("New Coordinate - \(marker.position)")
}
```

Comment: @ArielGemilang Welcome mate :)

Comment: it helps me too